# Cannot alter output file type attribute on an AVAssetExportSession after an export has started

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am using `AVAssetExportSession` to export a file

I made a routine that, if export fails then it should restart export method to make sure file is exported successfully.

When export method is restarted I get this error on the line

```
exportSession.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
```

Error is:

```
Cannot alter output file type attribute on an AVAssetExportSession after an export has started
```

How to release `AVAssetExportSession` to avoid this error if I am using ARC policy.

Comment: Have you tried setting exportSession to nil? I mean try to reinstantiate it when import fails

Comment: @Eugene, yes. But still same issue.

Comment: yes tried re-initiating it too, but that doesn't work aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Please add these two lines two times to your code:

```
-(IBAction)...
{
     //cancel the export
     [exportSession cancelExport];
     exportSession = nil;

     ...

     [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)

     ...

         //cancel the export
         [exportSession cancelExport];
         exportSession = nil;
     }];
}
```